# TreeView TreeNodeCollection Key

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms, treeview

The TreeView uses in its underlying implementation the TreeNodeCollection. The TreeNodeCollection in almost every overload of the add method asks for a key.

It also implements indexOfKey and ContainsKey yet there appears to be no way to determine the key of a node from the node itself or from any of the events you would typically use such as TreeView_AfterSelect().

**Am I correct or is there in fact someway to retrieve the key from a node or event which I have overlooked? And assuming I am correct. Why on earth was it implemented in such a way? 
The only thing I could think of was that perhaps TreeNodeCollection.Key is deprecated? But I see no mention of this…**

PS: I am aware of the TreeNode.Tag property and how it can be used to the same effect.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Take a look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3dbdy3xf.aspx). In the remarks you'll find the following

> The Name property corresponds to the key for a TreeNode in the TreeNodeCollection.