# treeview & add method & key parameter

Tags: c#, parameters, treeview, addition

I used a treeview in my windows application.
I add a node to this treeview with add method.

```
treeview1.SelectedNode.Nodes.Add("1","name");
```

That "1" is key parameter and "name" is the text of node.
Now I want to get key parameter.
What I must to do?
Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [TreeView TreeNodeCollection Key](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4385344/treeview-treenodecollection-key)

Answer (score 0):

just look at indexer overloads
    myTreeView.Nodes[Key]